# How to deal with byte fields in JSON files in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, azure, avro

I am trying to extract information out of an event from a Azure event hub. The events come in the avro format and I can read them into Python. The issue is the body of the event is contained in a byte field and I can't find a way to convert this easily into a Python dict without manually converting the field from a string to a dict. The event has the form when I print it out in python.

```
{
  "Body": b'{
    "records": [
      {
         "event1": ...
      },
      {
         "event2": ...
      }
    ]
  },
  "other_fields": ...
}
```

Comment: That's not a JSON file.

Comment: Did you try `json.reads()` or `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: Does the event come as JSON or a python dict? Your example is not valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure what to call it and presumed it was valid JSON. What I've shown is the form of the event when I print it in python after its parsed. In hindsight my question maybe should have been converting a python byte field into a dict.

Comment: @gilch Thanks `ast.literal_eval()` was what I needed. My question was badly written and it was a byte field in a python dict that needed processed

Answer (score 0):

To convert the byte string to a normal string, you can `decode()` it. After that, you should be able to `json.loads()` the string.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```py
# Get the bytes
byte_string = event["Body"]
# Convert to normal string
normal_string = byte_string.decode()
# Turn it into a json object
json_object = json.loads(normal_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
 
#convert byte to string
a=b'{"Body": {"records": [{"event1": "111"},{"event2": "222"}]},"other_fields": 333}'.decode("utf-8")
 
#convert string to json
d = json.loads(a)
 
print ('event1 result=' + d['Body']['records'][0]['event1']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse text into data structures using methods like `json.reads()` or `ast.literal_eval()`, depending on the format.